# How to have access Context in didChangeAppLifecycleState lifecycle hook using flutter HookWidget?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I'm trying to access context so i can read my provider but since this lifecycle hook is out side the widget tree. it's not accessible. is there a way to get access to context?

Comment: Please provide a code listing of you've tried already.

Comment: You need to provide a wider context.

Answer (score 5):

I researched a little bit and finally discussed with narcodico from the flutter bloc community, so the credits are for him.

Therefore, mixin `WidgetsBindingObserver` on a state class, the `context` is available even in the overrides like `didChangeAppLifecycleState` since they are part of the state class.

Also, take in consideration to move to BlocProvider above the state widget.

Example

```dart
class HomePageProvider extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => getIt<InAppPurchasesBloc>(),
      child: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _HomePageState();
  }
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
...
  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
      context
          .read<InAppPurchasesBloc>()
          .add(const InAppPurchasesEvent.getPurchaserInfo());
    }
  }
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid you can't access context inside didChangeAppLifecycleState.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested, you can save your scaffold state in a global key, and access the context from its current state.

Comment: Do you have an example? Thank you!

Comment: I found a solution and posted as an answer down below.

Comment: `final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();`

Then you can access it like

` _scaffoldKey.currentState.context.read....`, 

make sure you add your key to the Scaffold widget

Comment: You can accept my solution because is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using the [Riverpod](https://riverpod.dev) package instead of Provider. Riverpod is from the same author as Provider and considered the "better Provider", but with many improvements including Flutter independence, meaning it does not rely on a context to work, and you can use it almost the same way as provider.

Using Riverpod, along with Flutter Hooks, you can do something like:

```
// create a provider in a global context
final myProvider = Provider((ref) => myClass());

// access the provider inside your class
class MyWidget extends HookWidget{

  //access the provider using a hook
  final myClassProvider = useProvider(myProvider);
  //... your logic
  @override
  Widget build (BuildContext context){/* ... build widget tree... */}
}
```

Consider [this very useful and concise tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ls8Jm-viQkc) with how to use Riverpod with Flutter Hooks and StateNotifier, ChangeNotifier, etc...

Comment: I'm using riverpod. I get ``useContext` can only be called from the build method of HookWidget`when i try using the provider inside the didChangeAppLifecycleState function

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useEffect` function, read more:
https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_hooks/latest/flutter_hooks/useEffect.html;

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
useEffect(() {

    //what would you write in initState

  },
);
```

Comment: the use effect is inside the build context, my function is outside